# Is there a way to compile GWT code in production mode using maven

Tags: maven, gwt

I am trying to compile the GWT code in Production mode so that I don't have any Dev mode code in my generated JavaScript file.  I set production mode to be true for my gwt-maven-plugin in pom file, as follows. But, I still get hosted mode code generated. What can I do, to compile in Production mode using maven? Is there a flag/property I can set in my pom file or *.gwt.xml file or somewhere else?

```
        <!-- Compile Using GWT -->

        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>

            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>2.5.1</version>

            <executions>

                <execution>

                    <goals>

                        <goal>compile</goal>

                    </goals>

                    <configuration>

                    <productionMode>true</productionMode>

                        <classifier>war</classifier>

                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>

                        <webappDirectory>war</webappDirectory>

                        <module>${Module.name}</module>

                        <extraJvmArgs>${gwt.extraJvmArgs}</extraJvmArgs>

                    </configuration>

                </execution>

            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

I see that in GWT example uses Ant to compile in production. When you compile in production mode, following gets called in its build.xml file. Hoe do I do this in maven? If this is ant specific, is there an example to use Ant with Maven without changing the existing maven structure?

```
<java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">

  <classpath>

    <pathelement location="src"/>

    <path refid="project.class.path"/>

    <pathelement location="../../validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar" />

    <pathelement location="../../validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar" />

  </classpath>

  <!-- add jvmarg -Xss16M or similar if you see a StackOverflowError -->

  <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>

  <arg line="-war"/>

  <arg value="war"/>

  <!-- Additional arguments like -style PRETTY or -logLevel DEBUG -->

  <arg line="${gwt.args}"/>

  <arg value="com.google.gwt.sample.hello.Hello"/>

</java>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven is just fine to compile it with - what example are you going off of for that execution so that you are missing the `phase` tag?

Try adding `<phase>prepare-package</phase>` before or after the `goals` block, then do a normal maven install - it should run gwt:compile before building your war file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added <phase>prepare-package</phase> before and after the goals and did mvn clean install but it still compiles in dev mode. What I am trying to do is to get rid of "isHostedMode" method generated by GWT dev mode compilation in my production JS file. "isHostedMode" method shouldn't be there in my production code.

Comment: That's not true actually - it will always be there so that when you deploy to a production site, you can still run dev/hosted mode to track down bugs if you have to. Others won't be able to run dev mode unless they have the actual Java source code set up on their computer, so there is no risk of someone taking apart your project using dev mode.